# mysql subquery limit alternative

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I want to select distinct from my last 200 record. So I have wrote query for this

```
select
   distinct(server_ip)
FROM 
    resource_monitor  where server_ip IN
    (SELECT server_ip FROM resource_monitor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 200
    )
```

But this show me error

```
this version of mysql doesn't yet support 'limit & in/all/any/some subquery'
```

what is alternative of this query?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: Make it 'last 6 record', and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct t1.server_ip
from (select server_ip from resource_monitor ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 200) as t1;
```